# Differentiating $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm trying to prove the following using differentiation.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$

Looking all over the place, I see no rules for deriving such sums.
If I use the limit function to find the derivative, I cannot seem to simplify it down to $n+\frac{1}{2}$.

$$\frac{d}{dn}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+h} k-\sum_{k=1}^{n} k}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+h}k}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{h}{n+k}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}n+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{h}k}{h}$$

Since I already know the derivative, I can solve the equation.

$$\lim_{h\to0}n+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{h}k}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}n+\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow\lim_{h\to0}\sum_{k=1}^{h}k=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h}{2}\Rightarrow\lim_{h\to0}\sum_{k=1}^{h}k=0$$

What have I done wrong? Where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from? How should I derive such a summation?

Comment: The sum only makes sense when $n$ is integer, so your $d/dn$ does **not** makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment, what you did doesn't make sense. If you want to prove the equality by using derivatives, you can use this :

**Hint** : Consider $$1+x+x^2+...+x^n = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}.$$ Derive this equality with respect to $x$ and look what happens at $x=1$.

Comment: But in $x=1$ the sum, and its derivate, loses sense. Then, you will try to apply Abel's limit theorem, which is not a "trivial" statement (however, it is not a hardly statement)

Comment: I do not see what Abel's theorem has to do here. Of course the derivative of the RHS can't be evaluated at $x=1$ but it is easy to take the limit.

Comment: When I derive and substitute $x=1$ I can't perform the division because $(x-1)^2$ is a division by 0. Should I use $\lim_{x\to1}$?

Comment: Yes. You will have to use Hospital rule.